# pointwise and uniform convergence of a succession $f_n(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

I have $f_n(x)=\frac{e^{nx}}{2+e^{nx}} arctan(n^{|x|})$. I've found $f_n(x)$ pointwise converge in R to a function $f(x)=0$ for $x<0$, $\pi/12$ for $x=0$ and $\pi/2$ for $x>0$.
I can't have uniformly convergence in all R because the pointwise limit isn't continuous so I study the two intervals: $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,+\infty)$

For the first : sup$_{x\in(-\infty,0)} |f_n(x)-0|=sup_{x\in(-\infty,0)} |f_n(x)|$ and $|f_n(x)|\le \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{e^{nx}}{2+e^{nx}}$ so $sup_{x\in(-\infty,0)} |f_n(x)| \le \frac{\pi}{12}$ so  can't say if there is uniformly convergence in $(-\infty,0)$.
If I consider intervals as $(-\infty,a],a<0$ I have uniformly convergence because $|f_n(x)|\le \frac{\pi}{2} \frac{e^{na}}{2+e^{na}}\to 0$.

It's right :   consider the succession $x_n=-1/n$ so $|f_n(x)| \ge|f_n(-1/n)|= \frac{1}{2e+1} arctan(n^{-1/n})$ and there isn't uniform convergence in $(-\infty,0)$?